# Why to explicitly mention filesystem type while mounting?

Tags: mount, filesystem

I want to understand the filesystem concepts of linux. I tried my best to collect info from internet before posting here .But I  really got confused when i read lot of sites on internet..What i understood is

1. When an OS(Linux flavor) is installed first time a file system is configured automatically on the hard disk which is nothing but the root file system may be ext.Now there will be an existing directory tree structure .
2. Whenver we are booting up,root partition of the hard disk  is mounted automatically to the root file system.(its there in `/etc/fstab` file).
3. When ever we want to view files in a storage device like floppy,usb etc we have to attach the device say `/dev/cdrom`  to the existing root filesystem tree.
   command is `mount -t iso9660 /dev/cdrom /mnt/mycdrom`
   I assume by default ext file system is there in the harddisk.`/mnt/mycdrom` is a part of the file system tree in the hard disk. Why iso9660 type(standard file system for a CD) is explicitly mentioned here ?

Also please suggest me if there any site which can give me a clear picture of entire linux filesystems,partitions,installation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, **what you're asking** in point number 3 is this:

> The Linux partition (and all the files inside it) uses an `ext` file
>   system, so why do we mention `iso9660` when we want to view a cdrom
>   (or `ntfs` if we want to view a Windows partition for example) when we
>   are actually mounting it on `/mnt/mycdrom`, which is part of the default `ext` file
>   system (root partition).

So here's my answer:

We specify the file system while mounting because we want to tell Linux how to read the data in this partition/device. All file systems have a different structure. For example, there's something called a "cluster" in a file system, and the size of this cluster is different in the different file systems. Let's briefly explain "file systems":

- In a [**FAT**](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/fs/fat/fat-1.html) file system, there are two tables: a FAT (index) table, and a directory table. These tables are the ones that say "this file is called `text.doc`, and it starts from this part of the partition, and has a size of this. This other file is called `image.jpg`, and starts from this... and so on. These "tables" are placed in a special static place at the beginning of the partition.
- In an NTFS file system, there are different kinds of tables, using different formats.
- In a CD (file system IOS 9660), there is a specific size of "unused" space at the beginning, followed by the data.

What I'm trying to say is that each file system has a different structure.

Now, in Linux, when you do the command:

```
mount -t iso9660 /dev/cdrom /mnt/mycdrom
```

What you're telling Linux is this:

- [**`mount`**](http://www.linfo.org/mounting.html): make the files in this device accessible to me.
- **`-t iso9660`**: this device uses the file system `iso9660` *(so now, Linux will know how to read the files from this device, because you told it it's an `iso9660` file system and Linux already knows/supports the file structure of `iso9660` and knows where its tables are and all that)*.
- **`/dev/cdrom`**: the device I'm trying to mount; the device I want to access.
- **`/mnt/mycdrom`**: the [mount point](http://www.linfo.org/mount_point.html) when I want you to mount this device.

<sub>Anyone, correct me if I'm wrong in the paragraph below.</sub>

So, this folder (or directory) **`/mnt/mycdrom`** is part of the default file system, which is the `ext` file system (the root partition). The directory itself technically does not have a file system of `iso9660`, but it's *showing* me the contents of a device that's using the `iso9660` file system; it's acting as the starting point of that file system.

The thing about the Unix/Linux file structure is that everything is under one base, which is the root directory `/`; it's a hierarchical file system structure. Unix/Linux places all partitions and other devices under that root directory, that's why you really can't say that *everything* under that root directory is `ext` <sub>< Correct me if I'm wrong on this last statement too</sub>.

---

Further reading:

- [**Mounting Definition**](http://www.linfo.org/mounting.html) and [**Mount Point Definition**](http://www.linfo.org/mount_point.html) are a very good read to understand mounting.
- [**General overview of the Linux file system**](http://www.redhat.com/mirrors/LDP/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html) is also a very good guide on...well...a general overview of the Linux file system.
- [**Filesystems explained**](https://www.guinpen.org/2009/02/new-article-filesystems-explained-part-1-what-is-a-filesystem/) is an article that briefly explains the difference between a file system, a partition, and their names.
- [**Filesystems**](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/filesystems.html) is also an article about file systems.

Comment: >Thanks for the reply and links.Surely i will go through the links.